# How to import ICS into S-Planner (Galaxy S7)

Tags: s-planner, samsung-galaxy-s7

How can I import an [ICS file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) into S-Planner on my Galaxy S7 ?
An ICS file is an exported calendar from another application.

Btw: I know how to use Google calendar and then sync S-Planner with it but I definitely don't want to merge Google calendar with S-Planner calendar. The calendar I want to import into S-Planner is an independent calendar.

If S-Planner cannot import an ICS file, an alternative would be to have a Google calendar imported (not sync'ed) into S-Planner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the ics is an attachment to a mail or somewhere in your storage. Just tap to open it like any other file, and choose S Planner to open. It will give an option to import the event.